# How to pass data to PHP from dynamic form created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php

How to submit below form(which is dynamically creating by jQuery) to PHP?

**Content:** The goal is to enter multiple row values to database. But the problem is, as for now, only one row value in entering to the database. How to enter all the input fields data to database?

*Add Row button:* Create a new row.
*Submit button:* Submit the form.

```js
$(".add-row").click(function(){
  $html = 
      `<tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="id" placeholder="Enter ID" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>
      </tr>`;
  $(this).closest("table").find("tr").last().prev().after($html);
});

$(".submit-form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // I am stuck here, 
  // I figured out something needs to be done here, but can't figured out what to do!!!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="id" placeholder="Enter ID" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>
      <!-- I've tried to using it as an array, 
      Like this: <input type="number" name="id[]" placeholder="Enter ID" />
      then tried to submit it to PHP, but didn't work -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="add-row">Add Row</button>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-form" name="submitNewData">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my PHP section I am trying to get the form value using POST method, But its only returning only one value. Now how to get all input fields value in PHP:

```
<?php
// To keep it minimal, simple & understandable, the sanitization part and other things is not given here
if(isset($_POST["submitNewData"])){
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST["id"]); $i++){
      echo $_POST["id"][$i] . " " . $_POST["name"][$i] . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Any guidance/suggestion will really help me!

Comment: Form field names need to be unique, every time you add a row you are reusing the `id` and `name` field names. In PHP (and most other languages), if instead you name the fields `id[]` and `name[]`, you will have an array server-side to work with.

Comment: I've tried to used it as an array, and then echo it my in my PHP code by `$_POST` method . But, only one row value is showing there.

Comment: Please provide the relevant PHP code

Comment: Updated with the PHP code. One thing to note, with the loop the data will insert in the database --> mysql.

Comment: You are still naming your fields `id` and `name` instead of `id[]` and `name[]`.

Comment: Should I change the `name` attribute to `class`? Then can I fetch data in PHP and insert into database with this approach? Any suggestion please? @RoboRobok

Comment: Nope, you should change your definition of `$html` to use `name="id[]"` (and `name[]`, respectively). It looks like you don't have `name=` there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments previously made, assign a name to both elements using the array notation ( `name='id[]'` etc ) in both the existing HTML & also the HTML string within the `Add Row` code.

FYI: The form **must** either wholly contain the entire table or itself be wholly contained within a single table-cell - straddling table child elements as above is invalid markup and can lead to unpredictable results ( modern browsers are more forgiving than they once were )

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery - Dynamic fields with PHP Processing</title>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
                $_POST['id'],
                $_POST['name']
            )){
                
                foreach( $_POST['id'] as $i => $id ){
                    $name=$_POST['name'][ $i ];
                    printf('<pre>Array Index:%d - ID:%d - Name:%s</pre>', $i, $id, $name );
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="number" class="id" name='id[]' placeholder="Enter ID" /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="name" name='name[]' placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <button type="button" class="add-row">Add Row</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="submit-form">Submit</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
        
            $(".add-row").click(function(){
              $html = 
                  `<tr>
                    <td><input type="number" class="id" name="id[]" placeholder="Enter ID" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="name" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>
                  </tr>`;
                  
              $( this ).closest("table").find("tr").last().prev().after($html);
            });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**example:**
[image: A completed form]

**Yields:**
[image: The POST result]

---

In the above you have `I figured out something needs to be done here...` only if you intend to do some sort of validation but it is not clear what you wished to actually do there. The `submit` button will fire off the request perfectly well as is seen here.

Comment: Few things to add, I was making two mistakes here. 1) I used `<form>` tag before only `<tr>`, that's why only one row value was submitting. I should use `<form>` tag after `<tbody>` or before `<table>` like you. 2) I wasn't using array in my `<script>` section, and I couldn't even understanding it. However, Now things are crystal clear to me after seeing your code.

Comment: Glad I was able to help but you need to think about the nesting of the form as per the comment I made above. Either the **entire** table is inside the form OR the **form** is inside a single table-cell. Other options of nesting forms/tablerows/cells are **not** valid.